# NoClassDefFoundError with new eclipse bundle

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I am informed by a customer that they are receiving an error. On the report they filed it is continuosly coming up with NoClassDefFoundError. It appears none of my other customers are having this issue. I'm not having this issue running the app on my Motorola Droid Maxx. The customer is running the app on a rooted Droid Bionic. Everything was working fine on my version at 2.3 but when I updated it to 2.4, this issue arose. I also replaced my computer with a new and now I am running windows 8 and installed the adt bundle. The only change I made to the file in question in changing a >-90 to >-85. Below is the code...I have also included below the code the error report. This is only happening on phone.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;


public class ConnectivityCheck extends Activity {

    TelephonyManager        Tel;
   MyPhoneStateListener    MyListener;
   boolean isGsm;
   boolean cellAvailable;
int strengthAmplitudeGSM;
int strengthAmplitudeCDMA;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);         

    ConnectivityManager connec =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0) != null)
    {
        cellAvailable = true;
    }

    if (cellAvailable)
    {
    /* Update the listener, and start it */
        MyListener   = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        Tel = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Tel.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    }

 if (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
     {
        startActivity(new Intent(ConnectivityCheck.this, LicenseCheck.class));
        if (cellAvailable)
        {
        Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }
        finish();
     }
  else if (cellAvailable)
  {
     if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED && strengthAmplitudeCDMA >= -90)
     {
         startActivity(new Intent(ConnectivityCheck.this, LicenseCheck.class));
        Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        finish();
     }
     else if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED && isGsm && strengthAmplitudeGSM >= 10 && strengthAmplitudeGSM <= 31)
     {
        startActivity(new Intent(ConnectivityCheck.this, LicenseCheck.class));
        Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE); 
        finish();
     }
     else 
    {

        startActivity(new Intent(ConnectivityCheck.this, ProtocolsMMenuActivity.class));
        Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE); 
        finish();
     }
  }
  else
  {
        startActivity(new Intent(ConnectivityCheck.this, ProtocolsMMenuActivity.class));  
        if (cellAvailable)
        {
        Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }
    finish();
  }

}

/* Called when the application is minimized */
    @Override
   protected void onPause()
    {
      super.onPause();
            if (cellAvailable)
        {
        Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }
   }

    /* Called when the application resumes */
   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
        if (cellAvailable)
        {
        Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
        }
       }


   /* Start the PhoneState listener */
    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
      /* Get the Signal strength from the provider, each tiome there is an update */
      @Override
      public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
      {


    isGsm = signalStrength.isGsm();
    strengthAmplitudeGSM = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
    strengthAmplitudeCDMA = signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();

     super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
 }
};/* End of private Class */
}
```

Here is the error report

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.emsprotocols.njalsprotocolspaidac.ConnectivityCheck
at com.emsprotocols.njalsprotocolspaidac.ProtocolsSplashActivity$1.onAnimationEnd        (ProtocolsSplashActivity.java:144)
 at android.view.animation.AnimationSet.getTransformation(AnimationSet.java:411)
 at android.view.animation.Animation.getTransformation(Animation.java:920)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2657)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11009)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2154)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2096)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1679)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2558)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4722)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with the r21 version of the SDK tools. Go into your project settings and then in the Java Build Path. If you expand "Android Dependencies" you will see that there is now duplicates of some of your .jars from your libs folder.

Remove any duplicates from the top level leaving just the ones in the Android Dependencies folder. Then do a clean of your project and you should be good to go again.

Comment: I did this and there were no duplicates. When I 1st imported the app into the new eclipse, I deleted the license library I originally used and re-added it with the new correct path.

Comment: Hmmm, that fixed my problem sorry. I did have to remove one project entirely and re-add it. However that probably won't help you since you only just added it to a fresh eclipse install.